# экспорт импорт bcp

Tags: sql-server, формат, bcp

Ну в целом хотел сделать экспорт таблиц, для тестирования. БД огромна, поэтому разработчики попросили лишь пару таблиц.
Решил сделать через утилиту bcp. В вот в чем вопрос
C:\Users\Администратор.NOBDSQLDB165>bcp "select * from [nedb-migration].[nedb].[NEDB_USER] " queryout D:\Data_Export\user.dat -c -U sa -P password -S SQLDB

Начато копирование...

```
SQLState = S1000, NativeError = 0
Error = [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server]Warning: BCP import with a format file will convert empty strings in delimited columns to NULL.
1000 rows successfully bulk-copied to host-file. Total received: 1000
```

Экспорт хоть и проходит, но уже при импорте наблюдается следующая ошибка

C:\Users\Администратор.TESTNOBDDB115>
C:\Users\Администратор.TESTNOBDDB115>bcp [nedb-test].[nedb].[NEDB_USER] in D:\Distr\user.dat -c -U nedb-test -P password -S TESTDB

Начато копирование...

```
SQLState = 22001, NativeError = 0
Error = [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server]String data, right truncation
SQLState = 22001, NativeError = 0
Error = [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server]String data, right truncation
SQLState = 22001, NativeError = 0
Error = [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server]String data, right truncation
SQLState = 22001, NativeError = 0
Error = [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server]String data, right truncation
SQLState = 22001, NativeError = 0
Error = [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server]String data, right truncation
SQLState = 22001, NativeError = 0
Error = [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server]String data, right truncation
SQLState = 22001, NativeError = 0
Error = [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server]String data, right truncation
SQLState = 22003, NativeError = 0
Error = [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server]Numeric value out of range
SQLState = 22001, NativeError = 0
Error = [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server]String data, right truncation
SQLState = 22003, NativeError = 0
Error = [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server]Numeric value out of range
```

Ошибка BCP-копирования in

Понятно что проблема с форматом, но уже день бьюсь меняю и так и этак не получается. Может кто сталкивался?

Answer (score 0):

Это может быть проблема с символом новой строки в файле .dat.

Можно попробовать добавить еще один дополнительный флаг в bcp:

```
bcp [nedb-test].[nedb].[NEDB_USER] in D:\Distr\user.dat -r "0x0a" -c -U nedb-test -P password -S TESTDB
```